# relation not found, this can be validly caused by a concurrent delete operation on this object

Tags: locking, greenplum

We have a query running on GreenPlum running postgres 9.4 which creates temp tables as follow:

```
 drop table if exists mytemptable;
    create temp table mytemptable as
   /select code here/
 distributed randomly; 

 drop table if exists mytemptable;
    create temp table mytemptable as
    /another select code here/
 distributed randomly;
```

and it repeats the drop/create 5 times for different purposes, using the same temp table.

It works in the current version we are using (8.4) but we are migrating from Postgres 8.4 to 9.4 and now this doesn't work, and we get an error related to a concurrent delete operation, so we suspect it is deleting the temp tables on a Process ID when the same table is getting accessed by some other Process ID, kinda running the 5 create table statements at the same time..

How can this be avoided? We're using the default postgres optimizer, when we switch on the GPORCA optimizer, this query works, but for other reasons not related to this query specifically, we have decided not to use the GPORCA optimizer.

Comment: Can you provide the error message? What does "kinda running" at the same time mean? Do you have 5 different sessions executing this code at the same time? Is the code in a function?

Comment: Hi Jon, no, i'm running this in pgadmin actually. The drop table / create table repeats 5 times sequentially in the code.

Comment: So this is executed with pgscript? What happens if you put the code in a function?

Comment: Yes, it is executed with pgscript, we haven't tried using a function actually, what the difference would be?

Comment: A function would make the entire set of commands execute in a single transaction.  I also wouldn't recommend constantly creating and dropping temp tables. Create it once and truncate it instead.